# My query is incorrect when trying to update a record in mysql via node but I can't figure out why

Tags: node-mysql, node-mysql2

This question is asked several times but specifically to this one I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: CONSTRAINT `products.image` failed for `apiDbInk`.`products`
```

Here is my syntax:

```
  mysqlCon.query('UPDATE products SET image = "blah blah" WHERE id = 261', function(err, res) {
    console.log('this is an error');
    console.log(err)
  })
```

The table is products and there's a column called "image", type "LONGTEXT"
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?